# Как реализовать автодополнение вводимого города и области в Android+php?

Tags: php, java, android, геолокация

Хочу чтоб юзер вводил наименование города и город автоматически дополнялся до нужного вместе с областью, как это реализуется? Где взять базу населенных пунктов для автодополнения? Куда смотреть? С чего начать? 
Хочется полностью бесплатное решение реализовать.

Comment: Скачайте классификатор ФИАС и ковыряйтесь на здоровье.

Comment: Прям точно android + php?

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу чтоб юзер вводил наименование города и город автоматически дополнялся до нужного вместе с областью, как это реализуется?

Первое что приходит на ум, это `AutoCompleteTextView`

Вот код [примера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862403/4728929), от которого можно начать отталкиваться:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestDoctor extends Activity {

  TextView latText;
  TextView lngText;
  AutoCompleteTextView autoText;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  private Filter filter;
  private static final int ADDRESS_TRESHOLD = 3;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_doctor);

    latText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latTextView);
    lngText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longTextView);
    autoText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDoctor);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        new AdapterUpdaterTask().execute();
      }
    });

    autoText.setThreshold(ADDRESS_TRESHOLD);

    filter = new Filter() {
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
          FilterResults results) {
      }

      @Override
      protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.i("Filter",
            "Filter:" + constraint + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > ADDRESS_TRESHOLD) {
          Log.i("Filter", "doing a search ..");
          new AdapterUpdaterTask().execute();
        }
        return null;
      }
    };

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line) {
      public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
      }
    };

    autoText.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  private List<SimpleAddress> getAddressesFromText(String address) {
    address = address.replace(' ', '+');
    HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
    InputStream inputStream = httpHelper
        .makeHttpGetRequest("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
            + address + "&sensor=false");
    String response = httpHelper.inputStreamToString(inputStream);

    List<SimpleAddress> simpleAddresses = new ArrayList<SimpleAddress>();
    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

      int size = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).length();

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String formatted_address = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
            .getJSONObject(i).getString("formatted_address");

        Double lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(i)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        Double lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(i)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");
        simpleAddresses.add(i, new SimpleAddress(formatted_address, lat, lng));
      }
      return simpleAddresses;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public class AdapterUpdaterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    List<SimpleAddress> simpleAddresses = new ArrayList<SimpleAddress>();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      Log.i("UPDATE", "1");
      try {
        simpleAddresses = getAddressesFromText(autoText.getText().toString());
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      }
      Log.i("UPDATE", "2");
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      Log.i("UPDATE", "3");

      int size = simpleAddresses.size();

      if (size > 0) {
        adapter.clear();
        Log.i("ADAPTER_SIZE", "" + size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          adapter.add(simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
          Log.i("ADDED", simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
        }
        Log.i("UPDATE", "4");

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        autoText.showDropDown();

      }
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
  }

}
```

Код лично проверил, за исключением маленьких доработок, рабочий.